# Why is "and so" often followed by a comma even though it's a conjunction?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

From [this](http://victoryediting.com/introductory-words-such-as-now-today-etc/) website, I found the following advice:

> If you have an introductory word (or two) that is being used as an
>   adverb (usually answers the question of when, where, why, or to what
>   degree), then no comma.

They give this example: "Tomorrow I’m going to get my hair done."

I thought this was the reason "and so" is often written without a comma. [This](https://fraze.it/n_search.jsp?q=%22And%20so%22&l=0#q=%22and%20so%22%20%2Fr%3As&findid=-1&ff=&ffo=true&l=0&t=0) is from the fraze.it search engine:

> And so your ending will be sort of a reflection back on how you saved
>   the world.

But then I remembered that "and so" isn't an adverb but a conjuction ...

Why do people often omit the comma after "and so"? Is there any grammatical rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *And so your ending will be sort of a reflection back on how you saved*
>   *the world.*

"And so" is not a unit, not a single constituent.

"So is used here in conjunction with "and", but it is just "and" that is a conjunction, functioning as **marker**. "So" is a separate constituent, a connective adverb meaning "therefore", functioning as **modifier**.